# Exchange Account shows 2 calendars instead of 1

Tags: exchange-2010, microsoft-office-2010, ipad

I've created multiple room mailboxes that work fine in Outlook.
However only 1 room mailbox shows 2 calendars when opened on an iPad.
The other room mailboxes do not have this issue.

When adding the room mailbox to another iPad, the same thing happens.
So I'm thinking it must be an Exchange issue.

[image: iPad]

When checking MFCMAPI it only shows 1 calendar.

[image: MFCMAPI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently "Rupel" on itself was the issue.
By deleting it, the problem was solved.
I however have no idea why this room mailbox had this issue.

[image: Fixed]